# Creating columns in listView and add items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm learning how to use the `listView` in a `windowsForm` and I have some problems that I hope to solve here. The first thing is when ***I'm creating the columns*** with the code below:

```
private void initListView()
    {
        // Add columns
        lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Id", -3,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Name", -3, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Age", -3, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }
```

**When I run the program, the name of the columns are not visible, they are all at the left corner, and I have to "drag" them to be able to read the text. What have I done wrong?**

And finally I wonder how I add items to the columns. Do I first create a object like

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(???);
item1.SubItems.Add("text");
```

Is each listViewItem objects a column or a row? How do I add rows of info? Preciate some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are passing -3 to the 2nd parameter of Columns.Add. It needs to be -2 for it to auto-size the column. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns.aspx (look at the comments on the code example at the bottom)

```
private void initListView()
{
    // Add columns
    lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Id", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Age", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

You can also use the other overload, Add(string). E.g:

```
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Id");
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Name");
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Age");
```

Reference for more overloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnheadercollection.aspx

Second, to add items to the ListView, you need to create instances of ListViewItem and add them to the listView's Items collection. You will need to use the string[] constructor.

```
var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] {"id123", "Tom", "24"});
var item2 = new ListViewItem(new[] {person.Id, person.Name, person.Age});
lvRegAnimals.Items.Add(item1);
lvRegAnimals.Items.Add(item2);
```

You can also store objects in the item's Tag property.

```
item2.Tag = person;
```

And then you can extract it

```
var person = item2.Tag as Person;
```

Let me know if you have any questions and I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to try this code later or tomorrow. Perhaps I can return to you if I have some questions about it.

Comment: it does not have any overload constructor for implicitly typed string array ?

Comment: @Charlie, I am assuming you are referring to the overload constructors of ListViewItem? If you want to create a ListViewItem with SubItems from the constructor, you can either use the string[] overload or ListViewSubItem[] overload. I am using new[] instead of new string[] because C# can automatically infer the type (which is string in this case). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should **add** `lvRegAnimals.View = View.Details;` (or set the View property in the designer).
Otherwise you only see the values of the first column.
..... Additionally I had trouble with auto size (-2) of all columns. When I set a fixed size to one column, the view showed all columns.

Answer (score 42):

I didn't see anyone answer this correctly.  So I'm posting it here.  In order to get columns to show up you need to specify the following line.

```
lvRegAnimals.View = View.Details;
```

And then add your columns after that.

```
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Id", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvRegAnimals.Columns.Add("Age", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking for this answer in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set property for the control:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: what does this property do >/

Comment: *what does this property do* - ListViews are used in the standard "Windows Explorer", so imagine **Details view** in the standard folder/file browser.

Comment: It will show grid structure. Pls. try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
            listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Target No.", 83, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("   Range   ", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add(" Azimuth ", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
```

i also had same problem .. i drag column to left .. but now ok .. so let's say i have 283*196 size of listview ..... We declared in the column width  -2 for auto width .. For fitting in the listview ,we can divide listview width into 3 parts (83,100,100) ...

Comment: Don't just post code, you need to add an explanation.